# appended input js not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

hi guys i am stuck in simple js. i am not perfect in js.please help me.
so basically i am doing open and close div on dropdown select in first div its working fine but when i add appended div that time its jquery conflig with first div

```
<div class="  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left special_offers">

    <br>

        <h3> TRANSPORTATION  </h3>

   <div class="controls_special_offers"> 



    <div class="entry_special_offers input-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">

            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> 

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="exampleInputindate"> transportation type </label>

                     <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form_line_only form-control " name="tr_seattype"> 
                            <option selected> Select Type </option>
                             <option > 7 Seater </option>

                             <option > 15 Seater </option>

                             <option > 34 Seater </option>

                             <option > 50 Seater </option>

                    </select>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>




            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> 

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="exampleInputindate"> Tour  </label>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form_line_only form-control className" name="tr_cartype" id="transport_cat" > 
                            <option selected> Select Tour </option>
                             <option value="PVT"> PVT </option>

                             <option value="SIC"> SIC </option>



                    </select>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 rate">    

                <div class="form-group ">

                    <label for="exampleInputindate"> rate </label>

                     <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" name="tc_rate" id="tc_rate" class=" form_line_only form-control" placeholder="Enter Price" value="" autocomplete="off" >

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 adult">   

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="exampleInputindate"> Adult </label>

                     <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" name="tc_adult" id="tc_adult" class=" form_line_only form-control" placeholder="Adult Price" value="" autocomplete="off" >

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6 child">   

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="exampleInputindate"> Child </label>

                     <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" name="tc_child" id="tc_child" class=" form_line_only form-control" placeholder=" Child Price " value="" autocomplete="off" >

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>



                    <span class="input-group-btn day_plan pull-left">

                            <button class="btn btn-success  btn-add add_col" type="button">

                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>

                            </button>

                    </span>

                </div>

            <br>

                        </div>





    </div><!--special_offers-->





$("body").on("change", "#transport_cat", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).val() == 'PVT') {
            $('.rate').show(); 
        } else {
            $('.rate').hide(); 
        } 
        if($(this).val() == 'SIC') {
            $('.adult').show(); 
            $('.child').show(); 
        } else {
            $('.adult').hide();
            $('.child').hide();             
        } 
    });




    $(function()

{

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)

    {

        e.preventDefault();



        var controlForm = $('.controls_special_offers:first'),

            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry_special_offers:first'),

            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);



        newEntry.find('input').val('');
$("body").on("change", "#transport_cat", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        if($('#transport_cat').val() == 'PVT') {
            $('.rate').show(); 
        } else {
            $('.rate').hide(); 
        } 
        if($('#transport_cat').val() == 'SIC') {
            $('.adult').show(); 
            $('.child').show(); 
        } else {
            $('.adult').hide();
            $('.child').hide();             
        } 
    });
        controlForm.find('.entry_special_offers:not(:last) .btn-add')

            .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')

            .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')

            .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');

    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)

    {

        $(this).parents('.entry_special_offers:first').remove();



        e.preventDefault();

        return false;

    });

});
```

if you want to see demo here jsfiddle[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/milan9898/kj2Lgux9/)

Comment: Please take your time to format your code and try removing the extra code blocks which are of no concern to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in jquery. Use [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) function with Select as described in the docs.

All you have to do is simple:

```
$( ".className" ).change(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).val() == 'PVT') {
        $('.rate').show(); 
    } else {
        $('.rate').hide(); 
    } 
    if($(this).val() == 'SIC') {
        $('.adult').show(); 
        $('.child').show(); 
    } else {
        $('.adult').hide();
        $('.child').hide();             
    } 
});
```

**EDIT:**
You have to apply the change even for the second `onchange` function as shown:

```
$( ".className" ).change(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).val() == 'PVT') {
        $('.rate').show(); 
    } else {
        $('.rate').hide(); 
    } 
    if($(this).val() == 'SIC') {
        $('.adult').show(); 
        $('.child').show(); 
    } else {
        $('.adult').hide();
        $('.child').hide();             
    } 
});




$(function()

{

$(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)

{

    e.preventDefault();



    var controlForm = $('.controls_special_offers:first'),

        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry_special_offers:first'),

        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);



    newEntry.find('input').val('');
 $( ".className" ).change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#transport_cat').val() == 'PVT') {
        $('.rate').show(); 
    } else {
        $('.rate').hide(); 
    } 
    if($('#transport_cat').val() == 'SIC') {
        $('.adult').show(); 
        $('.child').show(); 
    } else {
        $('.adult').hide();
        $('.child').hide();             
    } 
});
    controlForm.find('.entry_special_offers:not(:last) .btn-add')

        .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')

        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')

        .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');

}).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)

{

    $(this).parents('.entry_special_offers:first').remove();



    e.preventDefault();

    return false;

});

});
```

However, there is a problem. The problem is that you are accessing the two `select` tags with same class so the input tags are shown for both tags when only one of the options of select tag is chosen. Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj2Lgux9/2/)

Comment: i think you are not understand my question! whenever load page that time dropdown select and div hide and show working but when i append div and another div open that time select dropdown not working please check this [demo ](https://jsfiddle.net/milan9898/kj2Lgux9/) in this tour dropdown working in first div but not another div when click on + button